# How to read SNMP OIDs

Tags: snmp

I am trying to make a snmp v2c trap parser. I can successfully parse most of it but I got a bit stuck around the field sequence. The field sequence are list of OIDs and their corresponding values. The meaning of some OIDs I can get from different OID repositories from example `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0` is `sysUpTimeInstance`.

However, there are other OIDs that looks like this

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.3321.2.1.2.2.1.5.0
```

I came to know that the number 3321 represents the agents manufacturer. Still I dont know what this OID represents. Can I retrieve that using the MIB? If yes what is the procedure for that?

Comment: Read about using MIBs at  http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS

Answer (score 2):

If you have the MIB files containing the relevant information, you can use the `snmptranslate` utility from the Net-SNMP package to parse OID. Place the MIB files into a directory and use the following command:

```
snmptranslate -m ALL -M +<DIR> -Td -On <OID>
```

For the OID given in your question, the results in the following output on my system:

```
enterprises OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM   SNMPv2-SMI, RFC1155-SMI
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) 3321 2 1 2 2 1 5 0 }
```

Apparently, my system doesn't know anything about enterprise `3321`.

These enterprise numbers are assigned by the IANA and are available on their [website](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers), which also lists a contact for each enterprise which you could try to reach if you need a MIB file.